# Qsort on struct containing pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct, qsort

I'd like to write a program sorting rows of a matrix lexicographically by the qsort function. Since the compare function needs to know the size of each row, and there are no way to pass a third parameter, I make each row a ROW struct containing the row size. Then the problem is reduced to sort the structs in lexicographic order.

I write the default constructor, the copying cnostructor and the destructor. And I overload the assignment operator.

When I run the program on VS2010, it occasionally report the error below. When I run it in Linux with g++, it may modify some elements to unexpected status or run in core dumped.

Could anyone tell me where should I modify the code? Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

struct ROW
{
    int *ptr;
    int L;
    ROW();
    ROW(ROW &obj);
    ~ROW();
    ROW& operator = (const ROW& obj);
};

ROW::ROW()
{
    ptr = 0;
    L = 0;
}

ROW::ROW(ROW &obj)
{
    L = obj.L;
    ptr = new int [L];
    memcpy(ptr,obj.ptr,L*sizeof(int));
}

ROW::~ROW()
{
    if (ptr)
        delete [] ptr;
    ptr = NULL;
}

ROW& ROW::operator = (const ROW& obj)
{
    if (this != &obj)
    {
        //this->ptr = obj.ptr;
        if (ptr)
            delete [] ptr;
        ptr = new int [L];
        memcpy(ptr,obj.ptr,L*sizeof(int));
    }
    return *this;
}

int MyCMP(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    ROW *L = (ROW*)a;
    ROW *R = (ROW*)b;
    for (int i=0; i < (L->L); i++)
        if ((L->ptr[i]) < (R->ptr[i]))
            return -1;
        else if ((L->ptr[i]) > (R->ptr[i]))
            return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int R_size = 23;
    int R = 7;
    ROW* A = new ROW[R];
    //scanf("%d %d",&R, &R_size);
    R = rand()%20+1;
    R_size = rand()%30+1;
    printf("Row: %d, Column: %d.\n",R,R_size);

    for (int i=0; i<R; i++)
    {
        A[i].ptr = new int [R_size];
        A[i].L = R_size;
        for (int j=0; j<R_size; j++)
        {
            A[i].ptr[j] = rand()%100;
            printf("%d ",A[i].ptr[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("After sorting\n");
    qsort(A,R,sizeof(ROW),MyCMP);

    for (int i=0; i<R; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<R_size; j++)
            printf("%d ",A[i].ptr[j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    /*
    for (int i=0; i<R; i++)
    {
        if (A[i].ptr)
        {
            delete [] (A[i].ptr);
            A[i].ptr = NULL;
        }
    }
    delete [] A; 
    */
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
WINDOWS error
    TestArraySort.exe has stopped working 
        windows can check online for a solution to the problem.

      Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
      Application Name: TestArraySort.exe
      Application Version:  0.0.0.0
      Application Timestamp:    53dd642c
      Fault Module Name:    TestArraySort.exe
      Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
      Fault Module Timestamp:   53dd642c
      Exception Code:   c0000005
      Exception Offset: 00011727
      OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
      Locale ID:    1033
      Additional Information 1: 0a9e
      Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
      Additional Information 3: 0a9e
      Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Comment: I don't know too much C++, but I think you should rather be using `nullptr` instead of `NULL` and `0` during assignments to `ptr`.

Comment: You really should be using more STL if you're using C++. That is, you shouldn't use `new int[]` use `vector<int>`; and you shouldn't use `qsort` you should use `std::sort`. I haven't looked through all your code yet, but it looks like you're accessing out of bounds memory, and using C++ constructs would help with that.

Comment: In `operator=` you need to do `L = obj.L` before using it to allocate new memory

Comment: `ROW(ROW &obj);` should be `ROW(ROW const &obj);`

Comment: The comparator returns `0` if the lists are different lengths and one is a subset of the other

Comment: To show what I mean by using C++, I translated your code to use the STL and C++11: http://pastebin.com/FAYS7afC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're completely changing the row-dimension of your array *after* allocation.

```
int R_size = 23;
int R = 7;            // SET HERE
ROW* A = new ROW[R];  // USED AS ALLOC SIZE HERE

R = rand()%20+1;      // CHANGED HERE
R_size = rand()%30+1;
```

unless `R` ends up being less than or equal to 7 (odds are 7/20) you'll invoke *undefined behavior*. If it *does* end up being <= 7, you'll report partially sorted data. In a word, yuck.

---

**Doing This With Modern C++**

There are *multiple* ways you can do this with modern C++. This is one of them, which takes a step further by sorting the rows before insertion into the matrix, thereby allowing us to exploit the standard library comparator for containers of sortable entities. *This is only one of several ways to do this*, it is not, nor does not claim-to-be, some silver bullet. Rather it was chosen to demonstrate just some of the vast features the modern C++ language and standard library have to offer. Among them:

- `<random>` for random management. *Truly the cat's whiskers*.
- `std::vector<int>` for dynamic row storage.
- `std::vector<>` for dynamic *rows* storage.
- `std::sort` for sorting both individual rows and row-vs-row.
- ranged-for-loop usage (see if you can find it)

The standard library is *amazing* for accomplishing many, *many* tasks, and this is but a gnat on the arse of a fly on the bum of an elephant in demonstrating some of its capabilities. As you learn C++, spend time *every day* learning more of that library. You won't regret it.

So, some code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 prng{ std::random_device{}() };
    std::size_t R = std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t>(1,20)(prng);
    std::size_t R_size = std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t>(1,30)(prng);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(1,100);
    std::cout << "Row: " << R << ", Column: " << R_size << '\n';

    std::vector< std::vector<int> > rows;
    rows.reserve(R);
    for (size_t i=0; i<R; ++i)
    {
        std::vector<int> row;
        row.reserve(R_size);
        for (size_t j=0;j<R_size;++j)
        {
            row.emplace_back(dist(prng));
            std::cout << row.back() << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
        std::sort(row.begin(), row.end());
        rows.emplace_back(std::move(row));
    }

    std::sort(rows.begin(), rows.end());
    std::cout << "After sorting\n";
    for (auto const& row : rows)
    {
        for (auto x : row)
            std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Some sample output runs appear below, which will obviously vary form run-to-run.

**Sample Output #1**

```
Row: 9, Column: 19
90 16 9 66 78 38 28 52 27 61 24 42 10 52 83 27 74 52 20 
37 68 5 12 10 72 42 55 44 91 43 88 34 77 11 39 40 89 72 
47 67 86 74 13 88 88 65 64 60 81 10 42 26 58 5 6 88 83 
11 49 56 63 97 41 48 67 60 85 7 84 47 20 97 76 58 3 89 
83 15 87 63 88 10 54 20 16 82 5 33 69 21 23 16 36 47 3 
17 95 13 13 11 33 89 25 29 80 52 38 92 21 90 98 7 51 100 
12 4 74 64 11 73 9 1 24 28 49 92 57 69 20 50 53 80 20 
10 70 54 79 27 72 15 43 67 99 56 5 18 21 69 96 35 21 65 
90 75 26 86 45 92 47 70 27 81 18 23 64 71 51 31 10 81 94 
After sorting
1 4 9 11 12 20 20 24 28 49 50 53 57 64 69 73 74 80 92 
3 5 10 15 16 16 20 21 23 33 36 47 54 63 69 82 83 87 88 
3 7 11 20 41 47 48 49 56 58 60 63 67 76 84 85 89 97 97 
5 6 10 13 26 42 47 58 60 64 65 67 74 81 83 86 88 88 88 
5 10 11 12 34 37 39 40 42 43 44 55 68 72 72 77 88 89 91 
5 10 15 18 21 21 27 35 43 54 56 65 67 69 70 72 79 96 99 
7 11 13 13 17 21 25 29 33 38 51 52 80 89 90 92 95 98 100 
9 10 16 20 24 27 27 28 38 42 52 52 52 61 66 74 78 83 90 
10 18 23 26 27 31 45 47 51 64 70 71 75 81 81 86 90 92 94
```

**Sample Output #2**

```
Row: 10, Column: 15
13 33 61 44 2 69 89 95 84 29 24 87 16 96 74 
44 60 72 37 78 17 94 6 88 5 61 41 37 33 13 
56 53 26 4 67 32 50 41 21 79 41 21 17 97 85 
88 84 7 93 41 13 46 10 50 70 38 71 3 55 77 
82 53 53 71 77 33 48 36 25 82 73 58 67 63 56 
27 83 5 42 81 4 86 6 51 4 29 16 6 38 78 
94 5 87 13 4 76 66 47 97 72 55 63 96 78 43 
96 2 36 55 64 25 34 27 70 44 21 2 46 54 46 
83 85 23 48 42 14 19 89 37 73 3 15 38 41 41 
98 64 49 9 61 46 49 24 94 76 51 46 98 3 26 
After sorting
2 2 21 25 27 34 36 44 46 46 54 55 64 70 96 
2 13 16 24 29 33 44 61 69 74 84 87 89 95 96 
3 7 10 13 38 41 46 50 55 70 71 77 84 88 93 
3 9 24 26 46 46 49 49 51 61 64 76 94 98 98 
3 14 15 19 23 37 38 41 41 42 48 73 83 85 89 
4 4 5 6 6 16 27 29 38 42 51 78 81 83 86 
4 5 13 43 47 55 63 66 72 76 78 87 94 96 97 
4 17 21 21 26 32 41 41 50 53 56 67 79 85 97 
5 6 13 17 33 37 37 41 44 60 61 72 78 88 94 
25 33 36 48 53 53 56 58 63 67 71 73 77 82 82
```

**Sample Output #3**

```
Row: 19, Column: 17
28 40 51 8 76 81 57 43 66 4 52 81 88 88 92 16 16 
39 38 78 10 50 24 53 72 4 43 87 92 75 51 20 62 45 
76 93 5 84 35 92 54 33 1 41 96 8 70 80 21 25 10 
1 58 19 24 42 39 17 93 53 35 64 73 27 13 96 34 55 
13 99 94 54 52 14 73 50 32 2 16 64 40 14 71 70 62 
39 7 43 60 72 66 21 70 74 95 25 29 35 95 56 42 80 
74 41 88 51 55 73 45 41 8 17 8 2 64 91 66 25 37 
23 34 45 71 70 25 63 39 85 38 51 32 75 54 99 44 28 
76 84 81 52 1 22 20 89 13 11 48 82 8 21 67 9 15 
2 16 34 51 54 35 14 86 78 84 93 47 35 77 36 4 20 
23 13 36 24 14 83 38 7 84 9 97 87 62 82 27 43 3 
78 28 8 52 50 24 8 76 36 7 45 75 34 67 30 62 49 
27 52 90 65 19 88 81 78 44 53 51 59 22 51 75 52 40 
89 63 56 65 77 52 91 32 68 2 99 73 94 90 23 34 2 
67 18 43 46 30 16 44 10 86 27 76 7 71 22 15 60 20 
59 59 42 79 24 27 11 98 36 82 29 82 58 85 10 77 15 
44 83 58 21 1 33 30 77 17 94 16 81 36 40 73 46 28 
99 78 78 59 41 75 49 84 41 15 57 55 9 72 64 83 54 
48 15 4 92 37 13 76 1 46 68 52 66 39 29 76 21 70 
After sorting
1 4 13 15 21 29 37 39 46 48 52 66 68 70 76 76 92 
1 5 8 10 21 25 33 35 41 54 70 76 80 84 92 93 96 
1 8 9 11 13 15 20 21 22 48 52 67 76 81 82 84 89 
1 13 17 19 24 27 34 35 39 42 53 55 58 64 73 93 96 
1 16 17 21 28 30 33 36 40 44 46 58 73 77 81 83 94 
2 2 23 32 34 52 56 63 65 68 73 77 89 90 91 94 99 
2 4 14 16 20 34 35 35 36 47 51 54 77 78 84 86 93 
2 8 8 17 25 37 41 41 45 51 55 64 66 73 74 88 91 
2 13 14 14 16 32 40 50 52 54 62 64 70 71 73 94 99 
3 7 9 13 14 23 24 27 36 38 43 62 82 83 84 87 97 
4 8 16 16 28 40 43 51 52 57 66 76 81 81 88 88 92 
4 10 20 24 38 39 43 45 50 51 53 62 72 75 78 87 92 
7 8 8 24 28 30 34 36 45 49 50 52 62 67 75 76 78 
7 10 15 16 18 20 22 27 30 43 44 46 60 67 71 76 86 
7 21 25 29 35 39 42 43 56 60 66 70 72 74 80 95 95 
9 15 41 41 49 54 55 57 59 64 72 75 78 78 83 84 99 
10 11 15 24 27 29 36 42 58 59 59 77 79 82 82 85 98 
19 22 27 40 44 51 51 52 52 53 59 65 75 78 81 88 90 
23 25 28 32 34 38 39 44 45 51 54 63 70 71 75 85 99
```

Comment: Thanks! That's really a naive mistake. I shouldn't have done that way.